# use -auto-orient with imagemagick in Firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick-convert

I followed the Firebase functions tutorials from the firecasts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDLpEn3PbmE&t=338s to use firebase to create a thumbnail when I upload an image.

This all works well but when I upload an image that has been taken with an iPhone it's rotated (vertical image is saved horizontally). So I did some research about that and I came across the `-auto-orient` parameter from ImageMagick (http://magick.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient)

But I'm not sure how I add this parameter to the spawn function to take this parameter into account

My working code (just the part of it that is relevant) without the `-auto-orient`

```
...
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tempFilePath
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
        return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath]);
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Thumbnail created!');
        const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, '$1thumb_$2');
        console.log(`thumbFilePath: ${thumbFilePath}`);
        return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
            destination: thumbFilePath
        });
    }) 
...
```

the code that I tried with the `-auto-orient` parameter

```
...
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tempFilePath
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
        return spawn('convert', ['-auto-orient', tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath]);
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Thumbnail created!');
        const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, '$1thumb_$2');
        console.log(`thumbFilePath: ${thumbFilePath}`);
        return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
            destination: thumbFilePath
        });
    })
...
```

But when I deploy this to firebase and I try to upload an image I get the following error message which doesn't give me a lot of information about why it is not working

`Function execution took 6227 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'`

any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm hitting the same error.

Comment: No, haven't got time yet to investigate this issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue last night. Check out my answer below when you get some time to investigate!

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing the "Connection Error" message inside GCF. I did 3 things to fix it, though I am not entirely sure if only 1 was the cause or if it was all 3. They were:

- Unresolved Promises
- Lack of using the `callback()` function provided by GCF
- Using `require('child-process-promise').exec` instead of `require('child-process-promise').spawn`

Here's my code, which has been running 2x/second for 12 hours now without encountering the "Connection Error" message.

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const exec    = require('child-process-promise').exec;
const uuidv1  = require('uuid/v1');
const _       = require('lodash');

exports.processFile = (event, callback) => {
    const file         = event.data;

    if(file.contentType.indexOf('image/') !== 0) {
        console.log(file.name + ' is not an image');
        callback();
    } else if(!_.isUndefined(file.metadata) && !_.isUndefined(file.metadata['x-processed'])) {
        console.log(file.name + ' was already processed');
        callback();
    } else if(file.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
        console.log('This is a deletion event.');
        callback();
    } else if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.metageneration > 1) {
        console.log('This is a metadata change event.');
        callback();
    } else {
        const storage       = new Storage();
        const bucket        = storage.bucket(file.bucket);
        const parts         = file.name.split('.');
        const tempFilePath  = '/tmp/' + uuidv1() + '.' + _.last(parts);
        const tempFinalPath = '/tmp/' + uuidv1() + '.' + _.last(parts);

        console.log('Processing file: ' + file.name);

        return bucket.file(file.name).download({
            destination: tempFilePath
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Image downloaded locally to ', tempFilePath);

            return exec(`convert -auto-orient "${tempFilePath}" "${tempFinalPath}"`)
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('uploading modified file to ' + file.name);

            return bucket.upload(tempFinalPath, {
                destination: file.name,
                contentType: file.contentType,
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        "x-processed": "yes"
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('file uploaded successfully to ' + file.name);
            callback()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            callback(err);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to have the order of args right.

```
 await spawn("convert", [src, "-auto-orient", "-thumbnail",  "200x200>", `${dir}/thumb_001_${name}${ext}`]);
```

Will work, while if i have `"-thumbnail"` and then `"-auto-orient"` will not.

Per [imagemagick documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient)

> This operator reads and resets the EXIF image profile setting 'Orientation' and then performs the appropriate 90 degree rotation on the image to orient the image, for correct viewing.

[And](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#thumbnail)

> This is similar to -resize, except it is optimized for speed and any
> image profile, other than a color profile, is removed to reduce the
> thumbnail size. To strip the color profiles as well, add -strip just
> before of after this optio

So the issue was -thubnail was being run first, stripping of all the orientation information, and when -auto-orient was being run without orientation settings and setting EONNT error.